# Can we replace one chef-server .pem with another chef-server .pem?

Tags: chef-infra

One of my chef-server server is gone down. 
I have its .pem files and already setup a new chef-server with same IP and hostname.

I tried replaced same .pem files under /etc/chef-server but it doesn't work.

Is there any part I need to change in order to let another chef-server use the .pem files from different chef-server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These key files under `/etc/chef-server/` are read-only private key files of two chef clients plus one chef user:

1. `chef-webui.pem` - `chef-webui`
2. `chef-validator.pem` - `chef-validator`
3. `admin.pem` - administrator user

you just need to update 2) and 3) because 1) will never shared out of chef server.

Besides the first answer from @StephenKing, I would suggest use another admin user to update 2) and 3) because it's risky to update admin's public key with admin user itself (one mistake will cause you lose administration). So the steps are:

1. install new chef server
2. run command `knife configure -i` which creates another admin user
3. extract public key from your existing key file from your old chef server via `openssl rsa -in chef-validator.pem -pubout`
4. replace generated public key of client `chef-validator` by `knife client edit chef-validator` in vi.
5. repeat step 3) and 4) for the admin user by command `knife user edit admin` without worrying any mistake because you can always redo.

Comment: Thanks, this is really what I need and very clear step! (you all answered very similarly, though)

Answer (score 3):

The `admin.pem` and `chef-validator.pem`?

Yes, you would have to update those two clients. Use the `admin.pem` to get access to the new Chef-Server and edit the `chef-validator` and `admin` clients (`knife client edit admin`, then set the `public_key` entry while replacing line breaks with `\n`).

Answer (score 1):

My advise is to simply download the new chef server's keys and discard the old ones:

```
ssh myusername@chefserver sudo cat /etc/chef-server/admin.pem          > ~/.chef/admin.pem
ssh myusername@chefserver sudo cat /etc/chef-server/chef-validator.pem > ~/.chef/chef-validator.pem
knife configure --server-url https://chefserver \
                --user admin \
                --key ~/.chef/admin.pem \
                --validation-client-name chef-validator \
                --validation-key ~/.chef/chef-validator.pem
```

Dropping keys into the "/etc/chef-server" directory will not work. Like you, I also discovered that it's not possible to upload an existing private key into a new chef server.

If you look at the various APIs related to key maintenance:

- [Create client](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html#post)
- [Update client](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html#put)
- [Create user](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html#id45)
- [Update user](http://docs.opscode.com/api_chef_server.html#id46)

You'll notice they all return a private key. This mirrors the behaviour in the UI when one wants to create or regenerate a user. The private key is displayed with a warning that chef will not save it.

So, Chef generates the key pair and returns and discards the private part.